# How to include links in a D3 visualisation's text element?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to add a link to the text elements of this D3 visualisation:

http://bl.ocks.org/1093025

I would like to be able to click on "flare", "analytics" and navigate to another page or click in the rectangle and perform the normal action, which is expanding the sub-trees.

I tried a few things that didn't work:

- `on` event

I tried to add an `on` event to the `svg:text` element:

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
  .attr("dy", 3.5)
  .attr("dx", 5.5)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .on("click",function(d,i) { alert("Clicked on the text");});
```

- `foreignObject` element

I tried to add the `foreignObject` element like this:

```
 nodeEnter.append("svg:foreignObject")
  .style("float","right")
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .append("div")
  .html("<a href='#'>link</a>")
```

Even though it creates the link, it is an extra link, though (not the text element in the rectangle).

- link with `xlink:href` attribute

Finally, I also tried the following (in some combinations):

```
<a xlink:href="/svg/index.html">
    <text x="10" y="20">/svg/index.html</text>
</a>
```

But it didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: on('click' function () {}) should work as long as you a) have selected the right nodes and b) haven't disabled pointer events on text elements with css.

Comment: d'oh, that's right! The text node did have `pointer-events: none;`, which was preventing the action. Thanks! Would you mind adding an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.on('click', function () {})` should work as long as you

- have selected the right nodes
- haven't disabled pointer events on text elements with css

The pointer events seems to be catching people out as quite a lot of the examples have `pointer-events: none` for the text nodes.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with Matt's answer re: pointer-events... change this to `pointer-events: all` in the css.

And this is how I made the link in the force directed graph:

```
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

svg.selectAll(".node")
  .append("svg:a").attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return "generic.php?url=" + d.url })
  .append("svg:text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .attr("dy", 3.5)
  .attr("dx", 5.5)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
  //The End ;-)
```